# Electron contextBridge works on desktop but not on web

Tags: web, electron, fastapi, desktop, preload

My stack consist of Electron, React, FastAPI. I created a contextBridge in the `preload.js` file. Everything is working fine on the desktop application however when I am on the web, I get the following error below. If anyone knows what might be the cause of this please let me know where to start looking! I don't fully understand why it's a type error. Thank you!

`preload.js`

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
  rollDice: async () => {
    return await ipcRenderer.invoke("roll-dice");
  },
});
```

`error` in the browser console

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rollDice')
```

You can recreate the bug by following this:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template electron-python-fastapi
cd my-app
python -m pip install virtualenv
python -m virtualenv venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
npm start
```

Edit: in my `App.js` file `window.api` seems to be `undefined`. Any reason that might be the case for Web but not Desktop?

Edit: I added `console.log("running preload");` at the end of my `preload.js` file and seems like it doesn't preload the file when running on the browser(web).

`electron.js`

```
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });
```